# FragmentTabHost shows fragments overlapped

Tags: tabs, android-fragments, android-tabhost, overlap

I am using one FragmentTabHost inside one FragmentActivity, that has 3 tabs.
If i change tab from first page of each tab it works fine, but if i navigate throw fragments inside one tab and then change tab, it shows the new fragment overlapped to the old one.
Someone can help me?

This is the layout of FragmentActivity (fragments_tab.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/background_gradient">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/background_gradient" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

My FragmentActivity's code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

        @Override   
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setDB();
            setContentView(R.layout.fragments_tab);

            mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

            mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);


            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Home").setIndicator("Home",      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_home)),
                    HomeFragment.class, null);

            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Map").setIndicator("Map", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode)),
                    MapMenuFragment.class, null);
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Info").setIndicator("Info", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details)),
                    InfoFragment.class, null);
        }
}
```

Each fragment is created so:

```
public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to my question.
In my project every fragment is a different class that extend class Fragment. When FragmentTabHost tryed to detach the old fragment, it couldn't find Fragment object so it didn't remove anything.

I am not so expert, i am sure that there is a simpler way, but after many many headache i found this solution that works. 
This is what i did:

- I saved the current fragment for each tab into Object variable in the activity.
- I copied the code of FragmentTabHost into own class and changed the method doTabChanged when call detach or attach.

(i have 3 tabs "Home","Map" and "Info")

detach:

```
//ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
if(mLastTab.tag == "Home") ft.detach((Fragment) tabHomeFragment);
else if(mLastTab.tag == "Info") ft.detach((Fragment) tabInfoFragment);
else ft.detach((Fragment) tabMapFragment);
```

attach:

```
//ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
if(newTab.tag == "Home") ft.attach((Fragment) tabHomeFragment);
else if(newTab.tag == "Info") ft.attach((Fragment) tabInfoFragment);
else ft.attach((Fragment) tabMapFragment);
```

tabHomeFragment, tabMapFragment and tabInfoFragment contain the current fragments for each tab

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred because TabHost can't properly manage the fragment which you added.

I ever faced the same problem and solved by Fragment Container pattern.

FragmentContainer is a self defined class extends from Fragment. You can init each tab with a container.

Each Container manage their own child fragment by getChildFragmentManager().
You can add, replace, remove any thing as you want.

When Tab is changed, the container is also switched, there is no overlapping problem.

Here is a simple container I ever writted:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903349/1695108

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a quite old question, but i will provide my solution anyway so it can be usefull to anyone will read this question.
I had the same problem, and I realized that the problem was caused by calling

```
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
```

because making this call, the tabhost will inizialize this FrameLayout with all the fragments specified in `mTabHost.addTab` method

I solved my problem calling

```
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);
```

in this way, the FrameLayout R.id.tabcontent will be hidden (width=0, height=0), and than, simply implementing `OnTabChangeListener`, you can do this

```
@Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (tabId.equals(Frament1.TAG)) {
            t.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, Fragment1.newInstance());
        } else if (tabId.equals(Frament2.TAG)) {
            t.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, Fragment2.newInstance());
        } else if (tabId.equals(Frament3.TAG)) {
            t.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, Fragment3.newInstance());
        }
        //optional
        t.addTobackStack();

        t.commit()
    }
```

it should work

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar issue to this. I was selecting items in a ListFragment and then creating a new fragment and replacing the original list fragment in the tab's layout. I found that when I switched to other tabs, I'd have the issue of multiple fragments showing at the same time, overlapping each other, or I'd have fragments that should be showing disappearing. My solution was to clear the back stack when a new tab was selected, try adding this code to your onTabSelected() method in your TabListener

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if(manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    {
        manager.popBackStack(null, 
                             FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
```

Doing this solved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for reply @WingedRayeth, but i think that with your solution you ll clean the stack every time that you change tab. So, for example, if you navigate into first tab until fourth fragment and then change tab, when you ll return to first tab you ll restart from first fragment. 
I finally found solution, i ll explain below

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar situation and the following worked for me.

Check if the savedInstanceState if not-null, in that case, don't do the fragment transaction. It will resolve this issue.

```
if (homeFragment == null) {
    if (savedStateInstance != null) {
    homeFragment = (HomeFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(HOME_FRAGMENT);
    return;
}
// tie new fragment
homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(homeFragment, HOME_FRAGMENT);
transaction.commit();
}
```

Hope this helps.