# android, dynamically change a fragment inside a tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I'm trying to change the content of a tab that was created using `FragmentTabHost` and `getSupportFragmentManager()`, but I'm not sure how to do it. 
Here is what I have:

```
mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(this);
    setContentView(mTabHost);

    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),R.id.menu_settings);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("A").setIndicator("A"),
            A.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("B").setIndicator("B"),
            B.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("C").setIndicator("C"),
            C.class, null);
```

Each class loaded extends fragment and on `onCreateView` they inflate their layout.

the issue is that I have a dialog inside one of them ( for example A.class ), and depending of the response of the dialog, I need to navigate to a fragment D, placing it on tab C 
How should I do this?
I could communicate from the dialog to the activity that creates the tabs and specify the fragments, but I don't know how to change the fragment that is inside a tab ( in this case C ).

As a summary, I need to change fragment C to D inside a tab where C was placed.
I'm using the support library.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class acts like an fragment container.

for example:

```
public class FragmentContainer extends SherlockFragment implements OnBackStackChangedListener {
public static final String PARAM_CONTENT_FRAGMENT = "param_content_fragment";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_container, null);
}

public void replaceContent(Class<? extends Fragment> clz, Bundle args) {
    FragmentTransaction tx = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    tx.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

    // save
    Fragment curFrag = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);
    tx.addToBackStack(curFrag.getClass().getSimpleName());

    // change
    try {
        Fragment newFragment = clz.newInstance();
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        tx.replace(R.id.fragment_content, newFragment, clz.getClass().getSimpleName());
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Fragment f = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);
    if (f == null) {
        Class<? extends Fragment> claz = (Class<? extends Fragment>) getArguments().getSerializable(
                PARAM_CONTENT_FRAGMENT);
        FragmentTransaction tx = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        try {
            f = claz.newInstance();
            f.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            tx.add(R.id.fragment_content, f);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Several key point here:

1. Init the third tab with FragmentContainer.class and provide C.class as an fragment arguments. (argument key is PARAM_CONTENT_FRAGMENT)
2. onCreateView()
   Just create a FrameLayout with id @+id/fragment_content, this is where we place child fragment.
3. onResume()
   Place child fragment into FrameLayout if not exists.
4. replaceContent()
   Call this method When Fragment-C wants to change it-self to Fragment-D.

In Frament-C, for example:

```
((FragmentContainer)getParentFragment() ).replaceContent( D.class, null );
```