# fragment container not keeping the addBackStack android

Tags: android, fragment

I have implemented a fragment container to change fragments inside my tabs. (see: [android, dynamically change a fragment inside a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887065/android-dynamically-change-a-fragment-inside-a-tab))

I'm using a fragment tab host, and a framelayout (that its on a separate activity) to load my fragments into it. I have a button in my fragment that is changing into another Fragment. I've implemented that method, and I resolve the overlapping fragment problem. the thing is, that now, every time I press the back button my app exits (no matter where my fragment is).

I have checked that I a have the `tx.addToBackStack(curFrag.getClass().getSimpleName())` even tried with `tx.addBackStack(null)` before the commits, but still doesnt do anything. Could anyone help me? thank you.

Edited:

I'm already adding a tag to my tabhost.
this is my FragmentTabMenu.java

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_tab_menu);
        Resources res = getResources();


        mtabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); //id from the activity that hosts the tabwidget
           mtabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.FrameLayout1); //id from the other activity that only hosts the framelayout

           //passing the class that my container will execute on the onResume method 

           Bundle args1=new Bundle();              
           args1.putSerializable(PARAM_CONTENT_FRAGMENT,RegistoUtilizador.class); 

           //creating the tab
           mtabHost.addTab(
                    mtabHost.newTabSpec("RegistoUti").setIndicator("Tab 1",
                            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon_rui)),
                    ContentorFragRegistoUti.class, args1);
```

And this is my container class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_container, null);
}

public void replaceContent(Class<? extends Fragment> clz, Bundle args) {
    FragmentTransaction tx = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    tx.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

    // save
    Fragment curFrag = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrameLayout1);
    tx.addToBackStack(curFrag.getClass().getSimpleName());

    // change
    try {

        Fragment newFragment = clz.newInstance();
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        tx.replace(R.id.FrameLayout1, newFragment, clz.getClass().getSimpleName());

        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Fragment f = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrameLayout1);
    if (f == null) {
        Class<? extends Fragment> claz = (Class<? extends Fragment>) getArguments().getSerializable(
                PARAM_CONTENT_FRAGMENT);

      FragmentTransaction tx = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        try {
            f = claz.newInstance();
            f.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            tx.add(R.id.FrameLayout1, f);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Maybe i missunderstood what Framelayout id, i should be calling on my methods?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you the hint what to do :

Suppose 3 tabs in Whole App :

One Main Activity = TabActivity
Add three Tabs in this Activity
like :
Tab 1 = FragmentActivity
Tab 2 = FragmentActivity
Tab 3 = FragmentActivity

Tab 1 -> different Fragments
Tab 2 -> different Fragments
Tab 3 -> different Fragments

and So On :

save your preference at each Fragment

Then when On second launch of app you know which tab was selected before so trigger the intent for that FragmentActivity , now you are in that Tab then trigger the respected fragment in that activity..

Note : Seriously if you are thinking to recover the old backstack then its not gonna happen because the OS it self handle the backstack for FragmentActivity..

Comment: thank you for your answer, ive edited my post to make it more clear to understand my problem. (i hope) :)

Comment: i narrowed my problem to the following: it seems the backstack doesn't take into account any nested Fragments, only Fragments added to the FragmentActivity. Therefor i need a workarround. I think its better if i save the state of my entire fragmenttabhost and restoring it when the app iniciate onCreate if instance available. Any ideias or suggestions? :)

Comment: Yes ! can you please clearify what you really want to develop so i can give you any suggestion..

Comment: I want to keep the user's selected fragment everytime the back button is pressed (since it sends my app to the background destroying the fragments and the activity).When returning to the app, it loads the last fragment used by the user. my problem is also how to send that fragment to the my fragmenttabhost in order for it to load the proper fragment. i can save the name of the fragment where the user last pressed the back button, but how can i inicialise my tabhost with it!? Suppose the user was in the 3 tab, second fragment. I need to him to return to that postion when app launches. Thanks

Comment: ok good explainantion got some thing to share: 
Lets start from the begin :
are you able to save preference at the back button pressed before app i closed ??

Comment: actually i only have 1 fragmentActivity. I have created one container for each tab (extended from fragment)  that in turn will replace the fragments i want in(being those its childrenfragment). i can get the name of the container and the fragment that is showing when i press the back button (im using  onBackPressed() method). since i can only save strings in shared preferences (cant save bundles or argss) i retrieve my container and my fragment string to store in it. now how do make for a fragmenttabhost to load that container and fragment. im using the code showned, but can update it. thanks

Comment: Regarding to the backstack i decided to implement exit buttons (that will replace the nested fragments by the previous fragment) seemed a better solution, if i manage to save the state of my app. :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, first part is done. im calling the container and loading it using: mtabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("Activecontainer");

Activecontainer is my string that i get from sharedpreferences is has been tagged with the fragment name.

Now i only need to set the fragment. Any suggestion?
thank you.